# create-react-app как настроить eslint?

Tags: create-react-app, eslint

я до этого не трогал eslint...

могу я добавить настройки внутрь eslintConfig?

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
```

или надо создать отдельный .eslintrc и туда добавить настройки

и еше вопрос каким оброзом .eslintrc находится и запускается компилятором?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Настройка ESLint
ESLint разработан так, чтобы быть гибким и настраиваемым для вашего варианта использования. Вы можете отключить каждое правило и запускать только с базовой проверкой синтаксиса или смешивать и сопоставлять связанные правила и свои собственные правила в соответствии с потребностями вашего проекта. Существует два основных способа настройки ESLint:

Комментарии к конфигурации - используйте комментарии JavaScript для встраивания информации о конфигурации непосредственно в файл.
Файлы конфигурации - используйте файл JavaScript, JSON или YAML, чтобы указать информацию о конфигурации для всего каталога и всех его подкаталогов. ***Это может быть .eslintrc.*файл или eslintConfig поле в package.json файле, оба из которых ESLint будет искать и читать автоматически***, или вы можете указать файл конфигурации в командной строке .
Вот некоторые из параметров, которые вы можете настроить в ESLint:

Среды - среды, для которых предназначен ваш сценарий. Каждая среда имеет определенный набор предопределенных глобальных переменных.
Globals - дополнительные глобальные переменные, к которым ваш скрипт обращается во время выполнения.
Правила - какие правила включены и на каком уровне ошибки.
Плагины - какие сторонние плагины определяют дополнительные правила, среды, конфигурации и т. Д. Для использования ESLint.
Все эти параметры дают вам детальный контроль над тем, как ESLint обрабатывает ваш код.